# Setting "Pixels per inch" to match Macbook Pro Retina

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel, retina

Basically just a quick question from a newbie to Photoshop, recently i've been finding that my text on photoshop amongst other items in my designs were ending up blurry as a result of my retina display on my Macbook Pro, I have subsequently changed to the pixels per inch on the image to 227 pixels per inch (the exact PPI in respect to my screen) and the text is clear as day.

However I'm worried that on slightly lesser displays this will then appear distorted as a result?

So my question is, would the image appear pixelated on lesser displays or worse or would the image still be clear as day as it is showing on my screen currently?

Cheers!

Comment: Please note that in both answers (so far), there is no mention of dpi. Its pixels only, and even if you craft everything "for retina" it is still a moving target even within Retina capable systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, just double your pixel dimensions for retina. The result on less dense screens will still be crisp that way.

This is because it is an easy mathematical calculation to half the pixels on standard screens. If you were making it 2.6395 time larger for example, this could cause some blurriness as you are relying on the program (or browser if a web graphic) to do the more complex math with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 0):

for Retina ex:-sample@2x.png(600X400)

for standard 50% of retina ex:-sample.png..(300X200)